# Closest pair algorithm

Tags: geometry

I just studied the closest pair algorithm for finding the closest pair in 2-D , but I am having some confusion with the point that we have to look only for next 7 points in the strip . I understood the proof that we should check the next 7 points in the strip , but I am unable to find a case in which this will happen , such that we will have to check all the 7 points . 
Can anyone give me an example .

Comment: Please provide a reference for "the closest pair algorithm".

Comment: http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~cs251/ClosestPair/ClosestPairDQ.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different proof than provided in the link. I will show that among seven points in a rectangle of dimension $1\times 2$ there must be two at distance at most $\frac{5}{6}$.  Divide the rectangle into six equal rectangular parts of dimension $\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}$ each ($2\times 3$ parts).  By the pigeon hole principle there must be a part that contains at least two of the seven points.  However, the diameter of each part is $\frac{5}{6}$ and so those two points are at most this distance apart.

If you go through the points in random order then you need to consider six points at most and there are situations where you do have to consider six points.  However, if you go through the points from top to bottom (as suggested in the linked document) then I think that considering only five points suffices.  At least There is a situation where you need to consider five points. (Place them in an hour glass configuration and the bottom left can be closest to the given point.)